# Direct all traffic between Eth0:1 interface and VPN Tun0

Tags: vpn, openvpn, eth0, tun

If answered correctly this question will show you how to link a 2nd public IP address on a machine to a VPN server tunnel on that machine, so that the remote VPN client (running a server), sees this second IP as its public address. In effect the second public IP address will be the gateway to the remote machine on the VPN.

[ Main Server ETH0 and ETH0:1 and TUN0 ]

ETH0 = 192.168.1.11
ETH0:1 = 192.168.1.8

i.e. the server has 2 IP addresses

TUN0 is an OpenVPN interface to another remote web server
This is setup so that the local TUN0 address is 10.10.10.1
And the VPN CLIENT the (remote server) is a static IP of 10.10.10.100

So when the remote VPN CLIENT connects... it is given the address 10.10.10.100

If I then type 10.10.10.100 into the browser on the MAIN Server... the REMOTE CLIENT Web server will serve the page. This is why it was given a fixed IP of 10.10.10.100, so that it can server web pages. This is done in the OpenVPN config files. Its called "Giving The VPN Client a Fixed IP address", and is well documented.

If I type 192.168.1.11 ETH0 on any browser... the MAIN server delivers the page... as it should.

If I type 192.168.1.8 ETH0:1 on any browser... the MAIN server *also* serves the page... but I **DO NOT** want that... I want the 2nd IP ETH0:1 to go down the TUN0 and I want the remote 'client' machine to serve the page.

I thought that...

```
  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0:1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0:1 -j ACCEPT
```

would work... it does not.

I thought that...

```
  iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.1.8 -o 10.10.10.1 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i 10.10.10.1 -o 192.168.1.8  -j ACCEPT
```

no luck

Tried...

```
  iptables -A FORWARD -i 192.168.1.8 -o 10.10.10.100 -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A FORWARD -i 10.10.10.100 -o 192.168.1.8  -j ACCEPT
```

no luck

I am sure I am missing the concept completely... how to make ETH0:1 the second interface and the TUN0 behave as an isolated pipe, that the MAIN server cannot see. I am trying to give the remote VPN client server... one of the "public" interfaces on the main server... ie 192.168.1.8 ETH0:0

Thank you
Bob